# ValueError: Failed ot convert Numpy Array to

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello everyone when Im trying to compile my model I get the following error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

I first assumed that something is wrong with the size of the datatype of my inputs but they should all fit well while being by transforming to floats:

```
train_weight = np.array(train_weight).astype('float32')
train_room_humidity = np.array(train_room_humidity).astype('float32')
train_temp= np.array(train_temp).astype('float32')
y_train = np.array(y_train).astype('int')
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)
```

The code for network is the following:

```
n_outputs = 1
lr = 0.0005
def my_model():
    images = Input(shape=(100,120,3))
    #temp_apple = Input(shape=(1,))
    weight = Input(shape=(1,))
    room_humidity = Input(shape=(1,))
    temp = Input(shape=(1,))
    
    
    x = Conv2D(256, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', input_shape = (100,120,3))(images) #, input_shape=(None, 3750, n_features
    x = MaxPooling2D(5)(x) 
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    #x = Conv2D(128, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x) #, input_shape=(None, 3750, n_features)
    #x = Conv2D(128, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D(5)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    #x = MaxPooling2D(5)(x) 
    #x = Conv2D(32, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x) #, input_shape=(None, 3750, n_features)
    #x = Conv2D(32, 5, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(x)
    
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    concatenated_features = concatenate([x,weight,room_humidity,temp])#inputD
    x = Dense(64,activation='relu')(concatenated_features)
    #
# Check for the position of the dropout
    #x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=[images,weight,room_humidity,temp], outputs=x)
    
    optim = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, clipnorm=1.)
    #optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
    
    
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optim,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

To train the neural network I use the following test

```
#import eli5
#from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

model=my_model()
history=model.fit([X_train,train_weight,train_room_humidity, train_temp], y_train,
                  validation_data = ([X_test, test_weight,test_room_humidity, test_temp], y_test),
                  #validation_data=([X_val,val_weight,val_moisture,val_temp],y_train[val]), 
                  epochs=100, batch_size=100)
np.save('history_run_1.npy',history.history)
    
scores = model.evaluate([X_test, test_weight,test_room_humidity, test_temp], y_test, verbose=0)
#scores = model.evaluate([X_test,test_moisture,test_temp, test_weight],y_test, verbose=0)

print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[0], scores[0]))
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]))
   
loss_history4 =np.array(history.history["loss"])
accuracy_history4= np.array(history.history["accuracy"])
val_loss_history4 = np.array(history.history["val_loss"])
val_accuracy_history4=np.array(history.history["val_accuracy"])

y_pred = model.predict([X_test, test_weight, test_room_humidity,test_temp])
```

This is the full traceback:

````
<ipython-input-136-95142cb0d292> in <module>
      4 
      5 model=my_model()
----> 6 history=model.fit([K.eval(X_train),train_weight,train_room_humidity, train_temp], y_train,
      7                   validation_data = ([X_test, test_weight,test_room_humidity, test_temp], y_test),
      8                   #validation_data=([X_val,val_weight,val_moisture,val_temp],y_train[val]),```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1047          training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
   1048       # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
-> 1049       data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
   1050           x=x,
   1051           y=y,```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1103 
   1104     adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
-> 1105     self._adapter = adapter_cls(
   1106         x,
   1107         y,```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    263                **kwargs):
    264     super(TensorLikeDataAdapter, self).__init__(x, y, **kwargs)
--> 265     x, y, sample_weights = _process_tensorlike((x, y, sample_weights))
    266     sample_weight_modes = broadcast_sample_weight_modes(
    267         sample_weights, sample_weight_modes)```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _process_tensorlike(inputs)
   1019     return x
   1020 
-> 1021   inputs = nest.map_structure(_convert_numpy_and_scipy, inputs)
   1022   return nest.list_to_tuple(inputs)
   1023 ```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 ```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 ```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _convert_numpy_and_scipy(x)
   1014       if issubclass(x.dtype.type, np.floating):
   1015         dtype = backend.floatx()
-> 1016       return ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=dtype)
   1017     elif scipy_sparse and scipy_sparse.issparse(x):
   1018       return _scipy_sparse_to_sparse_tensor(x)```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1497 
   1498     if ret is None:
-> 1499       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1500 
   1501     if ret is NotImplemented:```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 ```

```~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    261     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    262   """
--> 263   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    264                         allow_broadcast=True)
    265 ```
````

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
273       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
274         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 275     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
276
277   g = ops.get_default_graph()

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    298 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    299   """Implementation of eager constant."""
--> 300   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    301   if shape is None:
    302     return t
```

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
99
100

````
```ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).```
````

Comment: Can you provide the complete stacktrace?

Comment: yes. I added the stacktrace. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you try by disabling eager execution. `from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution

disable_eager_execution()
`

Comment: @Sunshine Is your issue resolved now?